# PDF file downloaded with small size and can't be opened - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, alamofire

I'm trying to download a pdf file using a link from an API but It's always downloaded with size 5 KB and always the file is corrupted and can't be opened, The link is working fine as I've tried it, my code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


class DownloadOrderService {
    
    static let shared = DownloadOrderService()

func downloadPDFOrder(orderID: Int, completion: @escaping(_ error: Error?)-> Void) {
    let urlString = getJSON(strURL:"URL")
    
    let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL:NSURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
        debugPrint("***documentURL: ",documentsURL)
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(orderID).pdf")
        debugPrint("***fileURL: ",fileURL ?? "")
        return (fileURL!,[.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
    
    AF.download(urlString,method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (prog) in
        
    }).response { response in
        if response.error == nil {
            
            debugPrint(response)
            

            completion(nil)
            
        }
        else {
            completion(response.error)
        }
    }
    
}
    
}
```

All the print statements I have in my code result and response as well :

```
       "***documentURL: " file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71CB6514-5C19-423C-989C-B21F2CEFE65E/data/Containers/Data/Application/3F21E22E-469E-4BCD-8079-83BC4CE321F2/Documents/
    "***fileURL: " file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71CB6514-5C19-423C-989C-B21F2CEFE65E/data/Containers/Data/Application/3F21E22E-469E-4BCD-8079-83BC4CE321F2/Documents/1007.pdf
    [Request]: GET url
        [Headers]: None
    [Body]: None
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 200
    [Headers]:
        access-control-allow-headers: *
        access-control-allow-methods: *
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        Cache-Control: no-cache, private
        Content-Encoding: br
        Content-Length: 1344
        content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        Date: Fri, 19 Nov 2021 20:25:54 GMT
        Server: LiteSpeed
        Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjhPMFBvR2l6U2dwYk83OVIreWRqSUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidU5yeEttN1BlQlRyXC9YVkh2d1RUYjJib3J1WkNtUUhVXC9oSVBzS08ybkhBYU9DT0tGaCtRbElBZzJiN2VRRFFvIiwibWFjIjoiYWQ2Y2UwZjhjZGI1MGUyYzg5MDNmOTA2YTVmNDI3MDZhM2JmZWM1NDFlOTRlZDY2NGFkNjk0MGQ5NTJjYTRjZSJ9; expires=Fri, 19-Nov-2021 22:25:54 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; secure
        Vary: Accept-Encoding
        x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.11
[File URL]: /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71CB6514-5C19-423C-989C-B21F2CEFE65E/data/Containers/Data/Application/492B9611-A6BD-4456-BE3B-9E2419E11073/Documents/1007.pdf
[Resume Data]: None
[Network Duration]: 0.38273394107818604s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(Optional(file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71CB6514-5C19-423C-989C-B21F2CEFE65E/data/Containers/Data/Application/492B9611-A6BD-4456-BE3B-9E2419E11073/Documents/1007.pdf))
```

UPDATE:
I've even created another function which leads me to the same issue again:

```
func savePdf(orderID: Int) {
    let urlString = getJSON(strURL:"url")

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           let pdfData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: urlString)
           let resourceDocPath = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
           let pdfNameFromUrl = "Orderatak-\(orderID).pdf"
           let actualPath = resourceDocPath.appendingPathComponent(pdfNameFromUrl)
           do {
               try pdfData?.write(to: actualPath, options: .atomic)
           }
            
           catch {
               debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I have tried the link in the browser and downloaded it successfully and it's size was 3 MB

Comment: You can check the edit on the question now, I have included all the print statements and response as well

Comment: 5k doesn't be opened at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and trying different links, I've discovered that unfortunately, after checking with the backend dev, the issue was from the URL and both the codes above are working fine, you can just copy and paste them using your own URL, and don't forget to add the below attributes to your `info.plist` and set them to **YES** to be able to find the downloaded files if you are running the app in real device:

1. Supports opening documents in place
2. Application supports iTunes file sharing